# Getting error while configuring Swagger-ui with spring reactive

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, swagger-ui, webflux

While integrating `swagger-ui` with a reactive spring project generated using JHipster 7.1.0 for Java 11. I added the below dependencies.

The application has below dependencies of swagger

**POM dependencies**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-common</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Apart from that we added a configuration **SwaggerConfig.java**

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.StringSchema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.parameters.Parameter;
import org.springdoc.core.GroupedOpenApi;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OpenApiCustomiser;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Amazingbabbage", version = "1.0", description = "Documentation APIs v1.0"))
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi employeeGroupApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("all")
                .pathsToMatch("/api/**")
                .build();
    }

    public OpenApiCustomiser getOpenApiCustomiser() {

        return openAPI -> openAPI.getPaths().values().stream().flatMap(pathItem ->
                        pathItem.readOperations().stream())
                .forEach(operation -> {
                    operation.addParametersItem(new Parameter().name("Authorization").in("header").
                            schema(new StringSchema().example("token")).required(true));
                    operation.addParametersItem(new Parameter().name("userId").in("header").
                            schema(new StringSchema().example("test")).required(true));

                });
    }
}
```

```
{
  "type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Internal Server Error",
  "status" : 500,
  "detail" : "No primary or single public constructor found for interface org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest - and no default constructor found either",
  "path" : "/swagger-doc/swagger-ui.html",
  "message" : "error.http.500"
}
```

Please share your feedback or inputs if you have faced similar issues.

Comment: When both Spring MVC and Webflux are present, Spring Boot will configure your application to use Spring MVC only. (see : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.web-environment). You must remove spring mvn from your dependencies if you want a webflux application.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you formalize this as an answer. It will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have both Spring MVC and Webflux are present, Spring Boot will configure your application to use Spring MVC only. (see : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.web-environment)

You need to ensure that the Spring MVC dependency is not present in your project.